# Downloaded S3 file to airflow tmp\test\ to process python scripts. First time job ran file. Second time it abended with template not found

Tags: airflow, mwaa

I have requirement to download couple for files from s3 to aiflow tmp\test\ folder to process python script and load the file back to s3.

Step1 : created the folder
Step2 : download file 1 using bash script
Step3 : download file 2 using bash script
Step4 : download file 3 using bash script
Step5 : download file 4 using bash script
Step6 : download file 5 using bash script
Step7 : execute python script
Step8 : load python output to s3
Step 2 to Step 6(Download) running parallel in DAG.

I created DAG, it ran fine first time. when i second time few files downloaded and few download step(step3 & Step 5) abended due to template /tmp/test/ not found.

```
DEFAULT_ARGS = {
 'depends_on_past': False,
 'start_date': '2021-03-22'
}

with DAG(
  dag_id='generate_dag',
  schedule_interval='0 0/1 * * *',
default_args=DEFAULT_ARGS,
template_searchpath=['/tmp/test/']
) as dag:
remove_temp_test = BashOperator(   
    task_id="remove_temp_test_dir",
    bash_command=f"rm -rf /tmp/test"
)
get_usafacts_cases = BashOperator(
    task_id="get_usafact "url" --create-dirs -o 
/tmp/test/{cases_file}"
)


get_etl_script = S3DownloadOperator(
    task_id='get_etl_script_s3',
    s3_bucket='{{ var.json.etlconfig.SCRIPT_BUCKET }}',
    s3_prefix='/scripts/test.py',
    outpath='/tmp/test/',
    outfile='test.py'
)

get_county_pop_data = S3DownloadOperator(
    task_id="get_county_pop_s3",
    s3_bucket='{{ var.json.etlconfig.LAKE_BUCKET }}',
    s3_prefix='/test1.csv',
    outpath='/tmp/test/',
    outfile='test1.csv'
)

get_congdon_data = S3DownloadOperator(
    task_id="get_congdon_s3",
    s3_bucket='{{ var.json.etlconfig.LAKE_BUCKET }}',
    s3_prefix='/test2.csv',
    outpath='/tmp/test/',
    outfile='test2.csv'
)

get_hud_crosswalk = S3DownloadOperator(
    task_id="get_hud_crosswalk_s3",
    s3_bucket='{{ var.json.etlconfig.LAKE_BUCKET }}',
    s3_prefix='/test3.csv',
    outpath='/tmp/test/',
    outfile='test3.csv'
)

get_cbo_definition = S3DownloadOperator(
    task_id="get_cbo_file_s3",
    s3_bucket='{{ var.json.etlconfig.LAKE_BUCKET }}',
    s3_prefix='/test4.csv',
    outpath='/tmp/test/',
    outfile='test4.csv'
)

run_etl_script = BashOperator(
    task_id="run_etl_script_local",
    bash_command=f"python3 /tmp/test/{etl_script}"
)

remove_temp_test >> get_usafacts_cases >> get_usafacts_deaths >> get_etl_script >> get_county_pop_data  >> get_congdon_data  >> get_hud_crosswalk >> get_cbo_definition >> run_etl_script
```

Comment: Share your DAG code and what executor are you using.

Comment: We are using MWAA

Comment: mwaa means you run airflow on amazon. it doesn't say what version or executor and again please share your code.

Comment: updated the code and MWAA is using CeleryExecutor

Comment: Might be that you are running the python on a different worker? So file downloaded on worker_1 and python code runs on workesr_2. And because the file is not on worker_2 hence the error?

Comment: Agree with Peter. Your tasks may execute on different workers which don't share the same disk.

Comment: yes i agree,  Its running in difference worker. How to copy the tmp/* data into all the worker. Do we need to update any config parameter to achieve this ?

Comment: yes i agree, Its running in difference worker. How to copy the tmp/* data into all the worker. Do we need to update any config parameter to achieve this ?